# Python Linux dmidecode, how to obtain HW info by Parsing?

Tags: python, linux

I'm using Fedora 17 64bit, installed [dmidecode](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode) and [python-dmidecode](http://www.ohloh.net/p/python-dmidecode), in my search for a doc on how to use python-dmidecode, i've yet to find anything. I found an example while browsing the source but nothing else. Anyone familiar with this module and how to access it in python? Any documentation you can reference me to would be helpful.

I'm trying to obtain hardware specifications in Fedora 17:

**In C# using Management namespace, I was able to obtain all the following:**
 ***Will it be possible to obtain the same In Linux via Python?***

```
BIOS
 - Name

Motherboard
 - Manufacturer
 - Model

CPU
 - Name
 - Architecture
 - NumberOfCores
 - CurrentClockSpeed

Memory
 - Name
 - Manufacturer
 - MemoryType
 - Speed
 - DeviceLocator
 - Capacity
 - Model

Video
 - Name
 - VideoProcessor
 - AdapterRam
 - VideoMemoryType
 - VideoArchitecture
 - VideoMode

Network
 - Name
 - ProductName
 - Manufacturer
 - PhysicalAdapter

HardDrive
 - Index
 - Description
 - InterfaceType
 - Manufacturer
 - Model
 - Size
 - Partitions
```

Comment: If you've got a library that can expose these in Python, sure!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out, by using the following we can obtain all data that I need:

```
import dmidecode

def getBIOS():
    for v in dmidecode.bios().values():
        if type(v) == dict and v['dmi_type'] == 0:
            BIOSdict["Name"] = str((v['data']['Vendor']))
            BIOSdict["BuildNumber"] = str((v['data']['Version']))
            BIOSdict["SoftwareElementID"] = str((v['data']['BIOS Revision']))
```

We iterate the `dmidecode.bios().values()` to find each field of data. We can see which function to use by referencing the table below. Which is also located at this [link](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man8/dmidecode.8.html).

We then check the type of `'v'` to ensure its a `dictionary` *(That's what I'm using in my case)* and we check that the `'dmi_type`' is the correct code for what we are searching for.

For example:

```
   Type   Information
       ----------------------------------------
          0   BIOS
          1   System
          2   Base Board
          3   Chassis
          4   Processor
          5   Memory Controller
          6   Memory Module
          7   Cache
          8   Port Connector
          9   System Slots
         10   On Board Devices
         11   OEM Strings
         12   System Configuration Options
         13   BIOS Language
         14   Group Associations
         15   System Event Log
         16   Physical Memory Array
         17   Memory Device
         18   32-bit Memory Error
         19   Memory Array Mapped Address
         20   Memory Device Mapped Address
         21   Built-in Pointing Device
         22   Portable Battery
         23   System Reset
         24   Hardware Security
         25   System Power Controls
         26   Voltage Probe
         27   Cooling Device
         28   Temperature Probe
         29   Electrical Current Probe
         30   Out-of-band Remote Access
         31   Boot Integrity Services
         32   System Boot
         33   64-bit Memory Error
         34   Management Device
         35   Management Device Component
         36   Management Device Threshold Data
         37   Memory Channel
         38   IPMI Device
         39   Power Supply


       Keyword     Types
       ------------------------------
       bios        0, 13
       system      1, 12, 15, 23, 32
       baseboard   2, 10
       chassis     3
       processor   4
       memory      5, 6, 16, 17
       cache       7
       connector   8
       slot        9
```

If we wanted to get the BIOS Info, we would then reference `v['dmi_type'] == 0` this will return a dictionary. We can then create our own dict (in my case `BIOSdict = []` ) and add the key and value as so:

```
BIOSdict["Name"] = str((v['data']['Vendor']))
```