# Capture and parse output from external command inside Python

Tags: python

Though I am new in python,i wrote  list of array and i want to print the list of array of bios information? how to execute the external command in this script and capture the output and parse it.

Below code i have written execute the dmidecode | less command using os.popen() and store its output to the variable called package:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
f = os.popen("dmidecode | less")
package = f.read()
print 'Bios Information is:',package
```

After executing the above code:sudo python sample.py => output is has follows:

```
BIOS Information
    Vendor: *****
    Version: 1.40
    Release Date: 09/07/2009
    ROM Size: 1024 kB
    Characteristics:
            PCI is supported
            BIOS is upgradeable
            BIOS shadowing is allowed
            Boot from CD is supported
            Selectable boot is supported
            BIOS ROM is socketed
            EDD is supported
            Japanese floppy for NEC 9800 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
            Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
            5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
            5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
            3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
            3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
            8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
            CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
            ACPI is supported
            USB legacy is supported
            Targeted content distribution is supported
```

So now i want to parse the a value of:Vendor , Release date &  Version and that should provide the related values.

The question is i have to execute the external command in the above script,capture the output and parse it?
So anybody can help me to find out this problem?

Help me out i have browse but none document are available...

Comment: Better to give more explanation. Show them original array format and your commands(at-least sample)

Comment: you can refer the following stackoverflow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814428/python-linux-dmidecode-how-to-obtain-hw-info-by-parsing

Comment: I have no idea what the first program has to do with the second program.

Comment: My question is how to execute external command and capture the output and parse it? To the above code i mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions. Pun only one question per StackOverflow question. This   addresses only the first one.

To capture the stdout or stderr output from a program you can use [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

"Run command with arguments and return its output."

Example:

```
  import subprocess

  output = subprocess.check_output("dmidecode")
  print(output.decode("utf-8"))  # Convert from bytes to string
```

When you have the output available you can ask the question how to parse it, and what you want to do with the parsed data.

Comment: I got output but i want to parse the values of first 3 values and display the output one-by-one.@Mikko Ohtamaa

Comment: @rohit_777: For parsing the output open a new StackOverflow question with the sample output and what you want to do with the data