# How to access memory information like brand and frequency in Python?

Tags: python, linux, memory

I'm implementing an API for querying hosts for their information like "CPU brand", "Memory capacity", etc.

For CPU information, I use the `py-cpuinfo` library.

What tools can I use to for memory information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Linux dmidecode, how to obtain HW info by Parsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814428/python-linux-dmidecode-how-to-obtain-hw-info-by-parsing)

Answer (score 1):

You can use psutil libary to get the system information, like this, My RAM is 8GB total:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.virtual_memory()
    svmem(total=8589934592L, available=1590308864L, percent=81.5, used=7048126464L, free=293085184L, active=4578406400L, inactive=1297223680L, wired=1172496384L)
>>> psutil.virtual_memory().total
8589934592L
```

Comment: It doesn't give as much info as DMI would, but on the surface seems to address the question as asked. :)

Comment: Even with DMI, you can't get the brand or model.

Answer (score 0):

Parse `/proc/cpuinfo`, it's a text file.

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
...
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4670K CPU @ 3.40GHz
...
```

Same for `/proc/meminfo`.

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       16115164 kB
MemFree:         1778416 kB
...
```