# incluse executable file in python code

Tags: python

i want to protect my python file + py2exe whit DmiDecode for Windows ([link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/dmidecode.htm))
, bat i want to create standalone file!

Is possible include DmiDecode in python code (run in ram memory for get uuid ) with out write on hdd ?

my actual code is :

```
def lic():
    try:
        if hashlib.md5(open('c:\dmidecode.exe', 'rb').read()).hexdigest() != 'bca173dc4758676dd812c7632017d0ae':
            sys.exit(1)
        out = os.popen("c:\dmidecode.exe -s system-uuid").read().strip()
        if out not in licente_valide:
            sys.exit(1)
    except:
        sys.exit(1)

lic()
```

Comment: What information do you want that require dmidecode ? I'm pretty sure you can get it with raw python.

Comment: dmidecode is licensed under GPL. If you do include it, you must carry the GPL license information also

Comment: What about using python-dmidecode, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814428/python-linux-dmidecode-how-to-obtain-hw-info-by-parsing