# How to get computer serial number with python?

Tags: python, django

You know how I can access from python the serial number of the pc,
I know that with dmidecode in the terminal I can find it and I am doing tests,
 the main idea is to register in the DB connected to Django the machine that 
 I use in a record of a table

My_code.py

```
import subprocess

var = str(subprocess.call(['sudo', 'dmidecode', '-s', 'system-serial-number' ]))
print var
fo = open("datos.txt","wb")
fo.write("%s" % var)
fo.close()
```

I also use a library but it does not work or 
I still do not understand how to use it well

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean?

Comment: Does not work the code or do not know how to use it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Look for a library which wraps the call. The issue you will face is that the os will prompt you for a password and this will not be written to stdout. You could use a pseudo terminal to see the prompt. Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814428/python-linux-dmidecode-how-to-obtain-hw-info-by-parsing) answer? You may also look at using `pexpect`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you don't *quite* understand the `subprocess` interface.  Your call captures the return code of the process: successful completion gives you simply `0`.  You need to capture `stdout` and return that as the call value.

The current code *prints* the serial number, but *returns* the status code.